# Local Wordpress install plugin wont upload image

Tags: uploads, localhost

So what I have going on is a plugin I am using (simple ecommerence) is not uploading an image locally (using MAMP). This is what I have tried so far:

- The plugin uploads all the content (name, description, ect.) fine,
  just no media
- I can upload media in general via media area in the WP admin
- The plugin loads images in its own section under wp-uploads and I
  have its permissions set to read/write for all the users

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: what is the folder permission?

Comment: It's local development but the folder is set to read/write for all users.